# How to retrieve selected option's value in Laravel 5 dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, laravel-routing

My dropdown list is prepopulated with names using a 'Users' table. I wish to use the selected name's id to then fill a table underneath the dropdown list with that person's email, also stored in the same 'Users' table. Any ideas on how I should do that while keeping everything safe?

My form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="employee-select" class="control-label col-md-3">Select Employee</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="col-md-10">
             {{Form::select('user',$users, null, ['placeholder' => 'Choose employee...', 'class'=> 'select-block-level chzn-select'])}}
           </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

The controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $users = User::lists('name','id');

        return View::make('sickleaves.create')->with('users',$users);
    }
```

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('sickleaves','SickLeaveController');
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088714/mysql-select-based-on-drop-down-value

But with Blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function updateText() {
        var empName=$('#userdropdown :selected').text();
        empName = empName.split(' ');

        document.getElementById("firstname").value = empName[0];
        document.getElementById("surname").value = empName [empName.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you're using resource controller and you're sending form to a `store()` action. In this case you'll have access to selected user with:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->user;
```

Comment: I was hoping to have access to the selected option in the view. I'm trying to populate a table underneath the form, a simple 2x2 table with the column name and email. Name would be the one selected, and the email would be fetched from the database, based on which name is selected from the dropdown.